# How to debug a Dart client Side application using IntelliJ Idea Community Edition?

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, dart

I would like to know if it is possible to debug a client side web application using IntelliJ Idea 14.1+.

Until the moment I only have found some tutorials for Webstorm and IntelliJ Idea Ultimate Edition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you cannot do this because JetBrains IntelliJ Idea Community Edition does not intended for such use (web development).

Community Edition
A free and open-source IDE for Java, Groovy, Scala and Android development.

Ultimate Edition
A complete toolset for web, mobile and enterprise development.

Answer (score 2):

Open the Dartium devtools <kbd>F11</kbd> (in Dartium), search for the Dart source files set a breakpoint and reload the page (as in JavaScript).

You can also open the Observatory and use the debugger integrated there but this debugger is not yet as comfortable as the Dartium devtools debugger.

Answer (score 2):

For IntelliJ Idea 14.1+ (Ultimate Edition), You can use IntelliJ's JavaScript debugger for Dart debugging. I wrote the set up instruction for WebStrom. And it can also apply to IntelliJ Idea (with Dart plugin).

http://blog.ntaoo.com/2015/04/lets-start-dart-with-brilliant.html

The community edition doesn't provide JavaScript Debugger so it doesn't seems to enable Dart debugging. (Correct me if there's some way to enable it)

Comment: Why do you think that this is unfortunately? This is a JetBrains business and their decision.